# FFMPEG show an Image with specific duration in filter_complex chain

Tags: ffmpeg

I have trouble with showing images with a specific duration in filter_complex.

I have to use filter_complex, and getting error: **"No such filter: 'duration'"**

*So which filter do I need to use?*

```
ffmpeg \
    -i "music.mp3" \
    -i "01.mp4" \
    -i "02.jpg" \
    -i "03.mp4" \
    -i "04.jpg" \
    -i "05.mp4" \
    -filter_complex " \
        [1:v]scale=300:400,trim=0:2,setpts=PTS-STARTPTS[v1]; \
        // Correct filter needed here: \
        [2:v]scale=300:400,duration=2,setpts=PTS-STARTPTS[v2]; \
        [3:v]scale=300:400,trim=4:6,setpts=PTS-STARTPTS[v3]; \
        // And here:
        [4:v]scale=300:400,duration=2,setpts=PTS-STARTPTS[v4]; \
        [5:v]scale=300:400,trim=8:10,setpts=PTS-STARTPTS[v5]; \
        [v1][v2][v3][v4][v5]concat=n=5:v=1:a=0[out] \
    " \
    -map "[out]" -map "0:a" -t "12" -c:v "libx264" -pix_fmt "yuv420p" -s "300x400" output.mp4
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For single image inputs, use the `-t` and `-loop` options and remove the non-existent `duration` and the existing `setpts` filters.

```
ffmpeg \
    -i "music.mp3" \
    -i "01.mp4" \
    -loop 1 -t 2 -i "02.jpg" \
    -i "03.mp4" \
    -loop 1 -t 2 -i "04.jpg" \
    -i "05.mp4" \
    -filter_complex " \
        [1:v]scale=300:400,trim=0:2,setpts=PTS-STARTPTS[v1]; \
        [2:v]scale=300:400[v2]; \
        [3:v]scale=300:400,trim=4:6,setpts=PTS-STARTPTS[v3]; \
        [4:v]scale=300:400[v4]; \
        [5:v]scale=300:400,trim=8:10,setpts=PTS-STARTPTS[v5]; \
        [v1][v2][v3][v4][v5]concat=n=5:v=1:a=0[out] \
    " \
    -map "[out]" -map "0:a" -t "12" -c:v "libx264" -pix_fmt "yuv420p" -s "300x400" output.mp4
```

Unrelated to your Q but all inputs should have the same aspect ratio, so better to add `setsar=1` after all the `scale`s.

Comment: I got "More than 1000 frames duplicated" error message, any idea??